# If you submit a new portal to Ingress are you informed when it is activated in the game?

Tags: ingress

When you submit a possible location for a new Ingress portal are you personally informed (by email) if the portal has been accepted and been activated in the game, or does it just appear on the map?

Comment: Answers from before summer 2013 are obsolete now. Be sure to check my new updated answer. I've added one marvellous tip! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I submitted a clear image with geo-coordinates in the EXIF data (enable "Store Location" in the camera app settings) on December 14th, 2012.

The submission was approved by Niantic on February 6th, 2013,  **54 days later**.

> Success! Your Portal submission has been accepted and will be available for gameplay in the near future. Should you have additional questions, please visit our Help Center.
>
> -NianticOps
>
> The world around you is not what it seems.

I have yet to see the portal actually appear in the game, but found this in the Help Center:

> Expect a Portal to go live 2-3 weeks after it is accepted.

It sounds like the reviewing of submissions is very random....

======= UPDATE

Portal added during the early morning of Feb 21st, so **15 days after the approval email**.

Thats a grand total of **69 days** from submission to showing up in game.

Comment: Yeah, you get an email these days telling you it's live. Just remember to really zoom in if you are using the Intel map as it doesn't show lv1 portals from zoomed out view.

Answer (score 14):

No, at least I have not heard that anyone got informed.

3 of my portal suggestions were added to the game, however I have not got any message or confirmation yet.

Answer (score 6):

Sometimes you get an email stating that a portal you submitted has been accepted.

Most portals, however, seem to show up without notification.

The process seems to be somewhat random at this time. My own submissions (3 weeks ago) have not been replied to, a friend got his portal submission approved after two days.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are noticed by email and it takes usually <del>3-5 weeks</del> 120 days.

**In the email is**
 1. Name of your portal
 2. Hotlink to your portal in /intel
 3. Resized picture you submited
 4. Description text

### Note

- By rightclicking the 2) and 3), you can get permanent links which are the same for /intel. You can even parse the email using a script and you can construct your own maps via *MapsEngine*. For example look at my **[map of submitted portals](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zMJhSX-g38vA.kkO27q5LUCqI)**. Links vere parsed using a script to a `.csv` file and it was then uploaded to MapsEngine. Easy-peasy. :)
- When your portal gets added, you will receive 1 key of it.
  You will receive the key even if you have reached the maximum capacity (2000), but do not rely on it as it may change!
- You get **500AP** getting your portal accepted.

### edit

The new waiting time is approximately **120 days**.
There is a great mobile app [IPST - Ingress Portal Submission Tracker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.einzig.ipst), which parses all your emails and gives you a nice view about your pending/accepted/declined submissions.